# El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos - Subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, shell

Al intentar iniciar un subprocess para correr un script en Typescript me sale el siguiente error:

```
El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos.
```

Codigo:

```
import subprocess

# A continuación uso .stderr para obtener el error de salida, pero en casos normales usaria .stdout

command = subprocess.run([r"cd C:\Users\Maynar\TestVersion_8.3.16\logic", "-and", "npx ts-node ./TruthTable.ts"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stderr
print(command)
```

Ya probé cambiando la ruta por el uso de barras invertidas dobles, incluso separar la directiva `cd` en otro elemento del array, etc.

Comment: ¿Por qué debe ir junto esto `"npx ts-node ./TruthTable.ts"`?

Comment: Es la directiva para ejecutar el archivo ts